# Installing Ubuntu And Windows on same drive

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'd like to install ubuntu os on my dell laptop using Windows Installer.
The windows version i'm using is windows 7 home.
At the moment there is only one drive on the laptop, C , so the windows files are located on this drive. I wonder whether instaliing ubuntu on the same drive would cause any problems .

Any advice and opinion would be helpful,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify which Windows version you have so that you can get better answer to your question.

Comment: I've edited the post, i'm using windows 7 home permium

Answer (score 1):

If by windows installer you mean WUBI, then no, there will be no problems to the windows files except for the fact that there will be 1 giant folder the size of your linux virtual "partition".

Answer (score 0):

I've got better results (no booting problems) when I used Windows 7's own tool to create a second partition to install Ubuntu (e.g. 20GB) and a third partition for all my documents, pictures, videos, downloads, etc.). Swap partition (e.g. 4GB) can be created during Ubuntu installation.

Comment: He is using wubi not native install.